# What kind of power connector is this? Attached to Adafruit 32x64 Matrix

Tags: power, connector

I've been searching on Digikey and Mouser for this connector, but haven't figured it out. It's the same one that's on Adafruit's 64x32 LED matrix.

It's spacing is greater than 2.54 mm, so maybe around 2.9 or 3 mm.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please inline images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make an accurate measurement of your connector to decide if it's one of the following.

---

### VH-396

Could it possibly be a VH-396 from JST?

Pitch of these is 3.96mm, ie 0.156-in.
http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=262

[image]
A=(npins-1)*3.96mm

---

### KK-254

The picture at Adafruit (of one of its 64x32 displays) looks like the cable has a KK 254.  These are common as power connectors for floppy disks and some older small hard drives.  But the pitch is too small, 2.54mm.

[image]

https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_housings/0022013047

---

It also looks like Molex SPOX connector, which comes in 3.96mm and 5.08 mm.

Product family page: https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/spox

There are good dimensional drawings in there, here's a portion:

### SPOX 3.96 mm (0.156-in), also known as KK-396.

[image]
Hole is given as 1.8mm, pin therefore approx 1.27 mm square pin.

---

### SPOX 5.08 mm (0.2-in)

[image]
Hole is given as 1.8mm, pin therefore approx 1.27 mm square pin.

Comment: That's very close but there's no curve behind the wires, it's just a flat connection with a slight lip for the female end to snap onto

Comment: How accurately can you measure it?

Comment: The pins are .05" wide with ~.105" spacing between them, so I guess the pitch is 3.96 mm

Comment: See updates to answer, possibly VH396